# How to get SharePoint document library sub folders, folders count and files count recursively using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Assume that I have a Document Library called **FileManager** in SharePoint. In this file manager, I have multiple subfolders and each of these subfolders has multiple documents. Now I wanted to Calculate how many folders and documents are available.

Ex: Sub Folder A, Sub Folder B, Sub Folder C--> all these 3 subfolders are there under the file manager document library. Now Sub Folders may have many child folders. Now I want to loop through all these subfolders and its child folders to get the count of folders and files in it using REST API.

Like,
Sub Folder A ---> 4 Folders and 100 documents
Sub Folder B ---> 10 Folders and 22 Documents

this how It should come as a result.

How we can achieve this by using the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a reference of below method:

Endpoint: **Post** `/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/getitems`

Body:

```
{  
      "query" : {
                 "__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, 
                 "ViewXml" : "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /></ViewFields><Query><Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Lookup'>/sites/sbdev/Shared Documents/Pictures</Value></BeginsWith><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>"               
       }
}
```

There are 2 filters:

```
<BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><Value Type='Lookup'>/sites/sbdev/Shared Documents/Pictures/</Value></BeginsWith>
```

This filter is used for getting all items whose path starts with '/sites/sbdev/Shared Documents/Pictures/'

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>
```

And this one is for filtering folder/file

I have tested it on my SP online environment, could you please have a try?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. Can I get the complete code sample that you tried on your environment? If possible please zip it and drop here siva289162@gmail.com